# WiFi Direct Discovery Scan time set

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have developed a working App that uses WiFi Direct. It is based on the WiFiDirectDemo App that Google provides. When I press the scan button, the App scans for peers for a short period. I need to set that period for a longer time since I have to test it with a lot of devices. For instance let the App scans for peers for 1 minute. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could always listen for WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_CHANGED_ACTION events, and if the state WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_STOPPED comes before your time limit is reached, then just re-start the peer discovery.

Comment: But wouldnt that affect the results of what was previously discovered? I need to do this cause I have 20 phones connected to a server. The server sends a request for them to scan then 19 phones need to connect to 1 phone. I want that when they first scan to see that phone so that I don't have to rescan again.

Comment: Not really understanding the problem, nor your logic here. The original issue was that the scan time was not long enough, and the solution given is fixing that. Thus if you have other issues, please specify them separately.